# Determine the largest subset E of R such that sin(1/x) defines a continuous function on E.

Tags: analysis

So I believe the correct answer would be R without zero. However, I must justify my solution using relevant theorems, and I am having a difficult time with that.

Comment: $1/x$ is continuous away from zero. Sine is continuous everywhere. Composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: use sequential caracterisation of the limit.